# How to use ADFS Webfinger Endpoint?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adfs, webfinger

I'm very new to ADFS and the Web Application Proxy.  That said, I've recently setup an ADFS server and a WAP server and have all of the configuration setup to successfully handle SAML SSO to my custom application.

I am now attempting to use the Webfinger endpoint.  By default, that endpoint is enabled (and proxy enabled).  Unfortunately, I have not been able to get any meaningful response from this endpoint and am unsure even how to set it up.  Searching for "ADFS Webfinger" documentation has been fruitless.  Honestly, I can't find anything other than discussions of an Event Viewer error and other useless information.

I have attempted various combinations of URLs.

`https://my-adfs-server/.well-known/webfinger?resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-adfs-server%2Fadfs%2F/ls&rel=http://schemas.microsoft.com/rel/trusted-realm`

This gives me back a JSON:

`{
    "subject": "https://my-adfs-server",
    "links": [
        {
            "rel": "http://schemas.microsoft.com/rel/trusted-realm",
            "href": "https://my-adfs-server"
        }
    ]
}`

but it is the only URL I have found that returns anything.

`https://my-adfs-server/.well-known/webfinger?resource=acct:<myemail>`

This gives me a 404 with a valid email (acct).

What am I missing?  Even if that last URL was working, how do I resolve it to specify information that should be returned in the JRD document for this particular account?  Do I need IIS installed (I don't have it installed currently) and custom code?

Thanks for any help/insight.

Pink

Comment: Hi Karishma, what are you trying to do here. If you are looking for the OIDC discovery endpoint, you can access it via "https:<yourhostname>/adfs/.well-known/openid-configuration"

Comment: @SamuelDMSFT - There is an endpoint in ADFS at /.well-known/webfinger that is outside the scope of the openid endpoints.  I was under the impression that Webfinger was a standalone protocol that OpenID uses for discovery?  I simply want to return some discovery information that conforms to the Webfinger standard.  Thanks!  (Also, Karishma edited the question, but I asked it.)